# pass parameter to $.selector for ajax GET request call

Tags: java, php, ajax

i have pagination links echoed with a for loop like this '<< < > >>".

```
echo "<a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$prevpage'>< </a>"
```

somewhere within my codes i set the $currentpage  using GET request:

```
if (isset($_GET['currentpage']) && is_numeric($_GET['currentpage'])){
    $currentpage = (int)$_GET['currentpage'];
  }else{
         $currentpage = 1;
   }
  //the offset of the list , based on current page
  $offset = ($currentpage-1) * $rowsperpage;
```

and i have a session variable to hold search criteria selected by the user while he navigates the page links. The logical error i get is when user clicks any of the pagination link, the session variable wipes out and table displays without the search criteria. 
After intensive research i figured out i can use ajax but am confused on how to arrive my goals. THis is what i tried doing. please some help will do.

```
$('#pglink).click(function(e,$prevpage){//***i need to pass the current page parameter for clicked link 
e.preventDefault();
var pgNo = $prevpage;
$.ajax({
   url:"file.php",
   type: "get",
   data:{
   currentpage: pgNo }
   });
});
```

Comment: Check that https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Comment: Are you calling the ajax on the same page?

Comment: yes am calling the ajax on the same page